# how to add sample run mode for package installation

Tags: aem

I want to install a package (mypackage-1.0-local.zip) only for local environment. This package should not be installed in any other environments.Same as OOTB 'samplecontent'/'nosamplecontent' runmodes.
So for this I do not know how to achieve this. If I start AEM server with 'local' runmode then how package manager service will know whether to install this package or not based on runmode?

Answer (score 0):

If you are maintaining this in code, you can try to use /apps/${site}/install.${runmode} and place the package in that folder to install a package only to instances matching the run-mode.

e.g. Packages kept under /apps/${site}/install.author will be installed only in author instances.

Comment: as per my understanding install folder is where we keep jar file, but is this also applicable for zip package file as well?

Comment: Yes. It also works with zip files. Need to check if this behavior is only applicable for higher AEM versions or all. You can check in local once.

Comment: then how we-retail works? because in we-retail project there is no such install.samplecontent folder available. Also how is it possible to match install.${runmode} in the pom file?